# How do I disconnect a VPN?

Tags: vpn

I am using VPN Dragon and Hotspot Shield VPN. When it asks me to trust the vpn, I check the box and connect it, and it works fine. However, there is a problem which keeps bothering me: sometimes the connected vpn dialog stops showing bytes sent and received ([Attached screenshot link](http://s33.postimg.org/7hcs973en/2016_05_24_16_59_10.jpg)) and the vpn stops working at that point. I can not even disconnect it using the button in the dialog. The only way to disconnect it is, reboot. I am tired of rebooting.

Comment: Can you give us the screenshots for your Notification tray and Quick Settings whenever that key icon (that is, when VPN is activated) shows up in status bar? In Android M, I can click on that key icon and disable the currently active VPN. No need to reboot.

Comment: here is the link http://s33.postimg.org/fntdvhr0f/image.jpg

Comment: it really doesn't let me "manage" and there is no way to connect again until i reboot

Comment: What do you see under Settings app -> More (under Wireless & Networks category) -> VPN?

Comment: it takes me to the "add a vpn" settings where i don't see any VPN's it's empty

Comment: i am on stock android 4.4.2, Samsung

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the VPN app you're using. You should report it to the developer of the app and see what they suggest. It would be helpful if you can come back and post an answer afterwards.

Comment: It came out to be a bug

Comment: s33.postimg.org is not resolvable, the URL is bad. The whole domain is not resolvable.